# Why ListIterator<E> contains hasNext() method?

Tags: java, oop, collections

`java.util.Iterator<E>` has a `boolean hasNext();` method. `java.util.ListIterator<E>` **extends** aforementioned interface. Yet documentation shows that it also explicitly contains `boolean hasNext();` method.

Why? What did I miss about extension?

Comment: You missed nothing, documentation is allowed to document inherited things because it may decide to add different information. And even if the info is the same, nobody is stopping the one writing the documentation from including the same info in two places.

Comment: @luk2302 this is not just about documentation. [ListIterator](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ListIterator-source.html) explicitly defines a `boolean hasNext();` even though it is already inherited. But I agree that this is the only way to stick custom documentation to it.

Comment: Here, in particular, the difference is that the documentation for `ListIterator::hasNext` hints at the fact that a `ListIterator` can be traversed in two directions, while `Iterator` can only be traversed in one direction, so there's added information in [`ListIterator::hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#hasNext())'s description, mentioning "the forward direction", which is not mentioned in [`Iterator::hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca does it mean if `ListIterator` didn't have `hasNext();` everything would still work fine in Java?

Comment: @finca: yes, that's correct.